# My grunt-recess task won't compile properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs, twitter-recess

My `Gruntfile.coffee` has:

```
recess:
  dist:
    options:
      compile: true
      includePath: ['public/bower_components/bootstrap-less/less']
    src: 'dist/assets/ln.css'
    dest: 'public/stylesheets/ln.less'
```

And my `ln.less` is super simple:
`@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-less/less/bootstrap.less";`

When I do `grunt recess`, I get:

```
Running "recess:dist" (recess) task
Verifying property recess.dist exists in config...OK
Files: public/stylesheets/ln.less -> dist/assets/ln.css
Options: banner="", compress=false, footer="", compile, includePath=["public/bower_components/bootstrap-less/less"]
>> Parser error in public/bower_components/bootstrap-less/less/mixins.less
>>      643.   padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
>>      644.   &:extend(.clearfix all);
>>      645. }
Warning:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Current Bootstrap versions no longer support `recess` (since it stalls at quite outdated Less 1.3.x), they have switched to `grunt-contrib-less` (with minimum required Less version 1.6.x). See also these [topics](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+recess+extend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [comment by seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698714/my-grunt-recess-task-wont-compile-properly#comment36416126_23698714), I'm using the `grunt-contrib-less` task and that seems to work well.